# RethinkDB: RqlDriverError: Handshake timedout errors

Tags: rethinkdb

I am getting: RqlDriverError: Handshake timedout errors every so often which lock up my cluster.

The error stack is:

```
{ 
  "date": "Sun Dec 14 2014 07:59:14 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)", 
  "process": { 
    "pid": 10664, 
    "uid": null, 
    "gid": null, 
    "cwd": "D:\\home\\site\\wwwroot", 
    "execPath": "D:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\0.10.32\\node.exe", 
    "version": "v0.10.32", 
    "argv": [ 
      "node.exe", 
      "D:\\home\\site\\wwwroot\\server.js" 
    ], 
    "memoryUsage": { 
      "rss": 31940608, 
      "heapTotal": 27892736, 
      "heapUsed": 14846880 
    } 
  }, 
  "os": { 
    "loadavg": [ 
      0, 
      0, 
      0 
    ] 
  }, 
  "trace": [ 
    { 
      "column": 13, 
      "file": "D:\\home\\site\\wwwroot\\node_modules\\rethinkdb\\errors.js", 
      "function": "new RqlDriverError", 
      "line": 14, 
      "method": null, 
      "native": false 
    }, 
    { 
      "column": 36, 
      "file": "D:\\home\\site\\wwwroot\\node_modules\\rethinkdb\\net.js", 
      "function": "null._onTimeout", 
      "line": 490, 
      "method": "_onTimeout", 
      "native": false 
    }, 
    { 
      "column": 15, 
      "file": "timers.js", 
      "function": "Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout]", 
      "line": 112, 
      "method": "listOnTimeout [as ontimeout]", 
      "native": false 
    } 
  ], 
  "stack": [ 
    "RqlDriverError: Handshake timedout", 
    "    at new RqlDriverError (D:\\home\\site\\wwwroot\\node_modules\\rethinkdb\\errors.js:14:13)", 
    "    at null._onTimeout (D:\\home\\site\\wwwroot\\node_modules\\rethinkdb\\net.js:490:36)", 
    "    at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:112:15)" 
  ], 
  "level": "error", 
  "message": "uncaughtException: Handshake timedout", 
  "timestamp": "2014-12-14T07:59:14.810Z" 
}
```

I open the connection when the request starts, then close at the end. 
Im using the following to open the connection:

```
function createConnection(req, res, next) { 
    r.connect( 
        { 
            host: 'myhost', 
            db: 'mydb', 
            authKey: 'mykey' 
        }, function(err, conn) { 
        if (err) { 
            throw err; 
        } 
        else { 
            // Save the connection in `req` 
            req.conn = conn; 
            _conn = req.conn; 
            // Pass the current request to the next middleware 
            next(); 
        } 
    }); 
} 
app.use(createConnection);
```

and the following after routes have been processed

```
function closeConnection(req, res, next) { 
    if(req.conn){ 
        req.conn.close(); 
    } 
    next(); 
} 
app.use(closeConnection);
```

Is this the best way to manage the connections? Is How can I track more detail for this error.

Answer (score 1):

You're suppose to call `next` with the error instead of just throwing the error.
You also need to bind a listener on your connection and listen for the "error" event.

If you don't want to deal with that, you can use a connection pool, there are a few libraries around. You can also use rethinkdbdash that has an automatic pool (you don't have to acquire and release the connection, so there is no need for middleware).

Comment: Thanks for the reply Michael, you are indeed right about next(err), but that is only passing on the error. Unfortunately not preventing on changing the underlying issue.